# How can I have a Foo* iterator to a vector of Foo?

Tags: c++, iterator

If I have a class that contains a `std::list<Foo>` and which has public methods `begin()` and `end()` to return iterators for that list, how can I implement additional methods to return iterators to a `std::list<Foo*>`, preferably without using boost?

I'd rather not maintain a parallel container of pointers.

**Edit:**

I have a large code base that I want to improve. It has a tree-like data structure with a base class that has a method to return the children of the object:

```
class FooBase
{
    // ...
    virtual bool getChildren(std::vector<FooBase *>& children);
    virtual size_t getChildrenCount() const { return 0; };
    // ...
}
```

There is a templated class that implements collections of child objects:

```
template <class T>
class FooCollection: public FooBase
{
public:
    typedef typename std::list<T> ContainerType;
    typedef typename ContainerType::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename ContainerType::const_iterator const_iterator;
private:
    ContainerType _items;
public:
    // ...
    const_iterator begin() const { return itemsM.begin(); };
    const_iterator end() const { return itemsM.end(); };
    iterator begin() { return itemsM.begin(); };
    iterator end() { return itemsM.end(); };

    virtual bool getChildren(std::vector<FooBase *>& children)
    {
        for (iterator it = itemsM.begin(); it != itemsM.end(); ++it)
            children.push_back(&(*it));
        return (itemsM.size() != 0);
    };
    // ...
};
```

The code uses both the iterators the different `FooCollection<>` classes provide (where the class is known), and `FooBase::getChildren()` when it iterates over the tree. I was thinking that `FooBase::getChildren()` could be replaced with iterators, but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: is it a `std::list<Foo>` or a `std::vector<Foo>`. Your title says one thing, the question says another.

Comment: @Evan: Thanks, time for bed I guess. The type of container doesn't really matter though, is it possible to have both types of iterator for the same container?

Comment: Why do You need std::list<Foo*>::iterator? Can't You write a simple iterator Yourself that encapsulates std::list<Foo>::iterator and, when dereferenced, gives an address of some instance of Foo?

Comment: it might make it clearer if you tried to explain what you are trying to achieve, rather than trying to explain what you think the solution should be.

Comment: On the one hand, you say you want "iterators to a std::list<Foo*>", but on the other hand, you say you don't want "a.. container of pointers", i.e. a std::list<Foo*>. So I don't think I understand what you mean by the former.

Answer (score 3):

How about writing a simple iterator class like below and using it

```
class myIterator : std::iterator<std::list<Foo>::iterator::iterator_category
                               , Foo*, std::list<Foo>::iterator::distance_type
                               , Foo**, Foo*&>
{
public:
    myIterator(const std::list<Foo>::iterator& lIt) : it(lIt) {}
    myIterator(const myIterator& myIt) : it(myIt.it) {}
    myIterator& operator++() {++it;return *this;}
    myIterator operator++(int)
    {
        myIterator copy(*this);
        ++it;
        return copy;
    }
    myIterator& operator--() {--it;return *this;}
    myIterator operator--(int)
    {
        myIterator copy(*this);
        --it;
        return copy;
    }
    bool operator==(const myIterator& rhs) {return it==rhs.it;}
    bool operator!=(const myIterator& rhs) {return it!=rhs.it;}
    Foo* operator*() {return &(*it);}
private:
    std::list<Foo>::iterator it;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The dereference operator overload of `std::list<Foo>::iterator` returns a reference to the corresponding `Foo` object. Therefore, if you want the address of the `Foo` object at `std::list<Foo>::iterator` object `it`, then you could use `&*it`, which has type `Foo*`.

If you really need an incrementable iterator over the pointers, then you could write an iterator class that stores a `std::list<Foo>::iterator` member, say `it`, returning `&*it` upon dereference. Note that such an iterator class can only satisfy the const iterator concept for the reason that `&*it` is an r-value.

Answer (score 2):

This struct will help. It modifies the iterator such that dereferencing it returns a pointer instead of a reference:

```
struct PointerInstead : public list<Foo>::iterator {
  PointerInstead(const list<Foo>::iterator &x) : list<Foo>::iterator(x) { }
  Foo * operator * () const {
    Foo &f = *(*( (list<Foo>::iterator *) (this) ));
    return &f;
  }
};
```

Here's an example of its use:

```
  for(PointerInstead i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); i++)  {
    cout << i->first << '\t' << i->second << endl;
    printf("%p\n", (*i));
  }
```

Then you could write a pointerBegin() method that returns something like a PointerInstead(this->begin()).

Comment: @Daniel Trebbien: I've just noticed you beat me to a similar answer by a few minutes. I hadn't seen it yet.

Comment: Pretty good, but deriving from standard iterators is unsafe. For example, the `++` operator may be implemented as a free function `T& operator++ (std::list<T>::iterator &)` not a member function `T& std::list<T>::iterator::operator++ ()`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Does that mean the same issue of free functions applies to the answer of @Maciej Hehl also?

Is there a minimal way to create a type that behaves like another type in all respects, including in free functions, but with a small modification? What about a conversion operator? Would a conversion operator bring the free functions into play?

Perhaps do `private` inheritance from the `list<Foo>::iterator` and include an `operator list<Foo>::iterator& ()` converter?

Comment: I suggested `private` inheritance a few minutes ago, but I shouldn't have. Please ignore.

Comment: Maceij has the right idea. Conversion functions won't help. Rather than inherit, he overloaded each operator with a function using an expression involving the "base" class and the same operator. You can write a generic class which implements every operator as such, and inherit from *that*. (I think that should be a standard facility… oh well.) Also, I forgot, pointers are random-access iterators using the builtin, non-overloaded operators.

Answer (score 1):

Obtaining a collection or containers of pointers to the `Foo` elements in `std::list<Foo>` can be created, but it will be unreliable.  The problem is that the list owns the `Foo` items (it made a copy) and it is allowed to change the location of these items without approval.  So if you have a pointer to the 3rd element in the list, the list can move the element and your pointer will be invalid (without your knowledge).

A better solution is to dynamically allocate the `Foo` items and store smart pointers in different lists.  This allows you to have the items sorted by different keys.  For example, you could have *list1* sorted by the first field in `Foo` and another list sorted by the 3rd field in `Foo`.

You would have to come up with custom sorting *functors*, since the default operation would be to sort by the value of the smart pointer, which is what nobody really wants.

Comment: The list is not allowed to move the memory location of its elements in any operation (besides during removal, of course). The standard requires that iterators and *references or pointers* into list elements remain valid in any operation that does not imply the removal of the element element referred.